# Which mass spectrometry database search algorithms include the fragment mass accuracy in the calculation of protein scores?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, mass-spec

E.g. in a MASCOT search, the accuracy of the fragment ions in a ms/ms spectrum does not have any influence on the scores of identified proteins (unless the fragment ions are out of the set ms/ms tolerance of course).

I want to know other search algorithms that do include the fragment mass accuracy in the protein identification scores.
Also, if the protein scores are not influenced, i would like to know in which way other evaluation values of MASCOT or SEQUEST results are influenced.

Thanks for your time.